# Can it use DataBase from Assets - WITHOUT doing a copy?

Tags: android, osmdroid

I want to ship an app with an offline map (and another database) so it can be used without internet connection. The data-db has to be modifiable so I have to copy it to the app's data/data folder no problem with that.. it's < 1MB.

But the Map-DB is about 60MB and is not modified in any way, I don't see the need to put a copy in an modifiable space on the device.

Is there any way that osmdruid can use a DB from Assets (or Raw or anywhere else where I can put it) directly?

Don't know if this is really a osmdroid question, as I didn't find a way to use any DB from assets directly without copy.

If it isn't possible from assets - is there a way to ship it from marketplace other then that?

Answer (score 0):

Messy formulated question, but I believe the answer is no. You have to copy it from assets to SD/local storage.